# Bing WPF Maps in .NET Core

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, bing-maps

I'm trying to migrate an existing WPF .NET Framework application to .NET Core.

I have it all working except for a part that uses Bing Maps, as it is .NET Framework only.

I found a comment that suggests I might be able to use the UWP version of the maps in .NET Core, but I haven't been able to find any help on this.

Is it actually possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to host the UWP map control in a WPF application using XAML islands:

*[Host UWP XAML controls in desktop apps (XAML Islands)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands)*

This blog post gives some examples:
*[Getting Started with XAML Islands: Hosting a UWP Control in WPF and WinForms Apps](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/getting-started-xaml-islands-hosting-uwp-control-in-wpf-winforms-apps)*